# How to set a low process priority for everything spawned from a command prompt in XP?

Tags: windows-xp, process-priority

As a developer, once or twice a week I run a full build on my XP dev machine.

This will run at 100% cpu for 30 or 40 minutes, making my machine useless for anything other than basic browsing & email.

Is there anyway I can specify that for a given process (i.e. a command prompt) it and any process spawned by it will have a lower priority, say taking up no more than 60 - 70% of CPU, leaving my machine more usable.

I don't mind the build talking 30 or 40% longer, if I still have use of my machine while it's running.  I'd love to be able to throw more hardware at the problem, but that isn't under my control.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
start /low app.exe
```

Seems like it would do what you want. You can only start applications in the Low class though, not in BelowNormal.

Answer (score 3):

I just did this:

1. Spawn command prompt (start -> run -> cmd)
2. Task Manager, Right Click command, goto process
3. Set priority to Low
4. Ran a program from the command prompt
5. It had low priority

You might be able to make a shortcut or a wrapper program to spawn a prompt that's already low so you don't have to do the juggling.

Answer (score 0):

A new process will inherit the priority of its parent. 
EG: launching the Command Prompt and lowering the priority of it will then impact all child processes created --
Cant use the command line to run something?  Then lower the CMD prompt and lauch EXLOPRER to give you GUI access to whatever :)